# Batch Script input redirection

Tags: redirect, input, batch-file

Trying to run a program within Windows shell and send more input to the program and keep track of the output. Currently when running the program and sending more input it halts within the program expecting input and then the script sends the input after the program is quit.

```
cd \Users\user\Desktop\program
@echo "To start program, type "program -a [ipaddress] -r [port number] (EG: program -a          xx.xx.xx.xx -r 99)"
program -a xx.xx.xx.xx
show devs
```

the "show devs" command does not show up until the program is quit. How would I properly call this to get "show devs" to be called within the instance of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it!

```
echo "show devs" | program -a xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Check out the info from [this pipes and redirect reference](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/pipes.html).

Also, enjoy the crazy color scheme from 1995.

Comment: Piping it does not send it to the program that runs. The program seems to not accept the command at all. It no longer show up anywhere upon run or exit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frozig said, though remember to escape the pipe if running from a batch file.

```
echo "show devs" ^| program -a xx.xx.xx.xx
```

If that doesn't work then the input redirection can be done if you are able to let the batch create a small temp file.

```
cd \Users\user\Desktop\program
echo show devs>tmp.tmp
@echo "To start program, type "program -a [ipaddress] -r [port number] (EG: program -a xx.xx.xx.xx -r 99)"
program -a xx.xx.xx.xx<tmp.tmp
pause
del tmp.tmp
```

Comment: Unforunately neither one of those methods works. I am really quite lost at this point.

Comment: @JonathanFrigon What is the result of the second method? I don't know much about your program or when it is ready to accept commands, but the second method above should start the program then run a command to that program, assuming the program is ready to accept commands immediately after opening.

Comment: It runs the program but doesn't send the command. After I exit the program it then pauses. I don't see it sending the command anywhere in the program.

Comment: Could you verify that the temp file is actually being created? If not, you may have an issue with permissions in the environment that the batch is being run in, (try running the batch as administrator maybe?). You can slow the process down to check for the tmp.tmp file by adding a pause just after the file is meant to be created. `echo show devs>tmp.tmp` `pause` `@echo "To start program, type "program -a [ipaddress] -r [port number] (EG: program -a xx.xx.xx.xx -r 99)"`

Comment: I found that it is creating the tmp file but that inside the command prompt running the program as described above it is putting `echo show devs 1>tmp.tmp` inside the tmp file. any idea why that is? I have `echo show devs>tmp.tmp` in the batch file